# Python: evaluating a function with the argument taking multiple values

Tags: python, arguments

Asssume I have a function in python which returns the power of 2 of its input

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

Assume also I have a vector of integers 1,2,3,4,5

```
I = asarray(list(range(1,6)))
```

Now I want to evaluate the function `f` with all inputs from `I` and the results should be in a vector of dimensions 5 (A 1x5 array in Python). My desired result is then: `[1,4,9,16,25]`.

Can I get this result **WITHOUT** the use of a `for` or any other loop?

I have used `array` package

Comment: your `list(range(1,5))` will only give you the numbers 1 to 4, since the range function is non inclusive for the upper boundary!

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: You may use `map()` or a list comprehension, but these are merely loops in disguise. Or you may use the NumPy module, which has methods like `square()` that are automatically applied to every element in an array, but this too is merely a loop in disguise.

Comment: `result = [f(x) for x in range(1, 6)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

directly from the [pythontips](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) website...

use the `map` function!

```
squared = list(map(lambda x: x**2, I))
```

if you want to use your function inside the `map`-function, just do `squared = list(map(f, I))`.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the simplified problem I stated above. What if my function is depended on two or more variables and one of the was fixed? For instance f(x,y)=x^y and I want to keep y fixed at 2

Comment: then you would define `f(x,2) = x^2` and just call the same as above!

Comment: Why not use a list comprehension? I know OP said they didn't want loops, but it's simpler to use if you're binding one of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

There are generally two classical ways to apply a function to all elements of an iterable and store the results in a list. The more flexible one is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [f(x) for x in range(1, 6)]  # the upper bound is exclusive!
```

The other option is [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which allows a more concise notation, in particular if you have a named function available and do not need to use a lambda or the like:

```
result = map(f, range(1, 6))        # Python2: returns list
result = list(map(f, range(1, 6)))  # Python3: return iterator, so cast
```